# WebGL Draw a cube using 36 indices

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm trying to draw a `cube` using the same `indices` and `vertices` used in three.js `BoxGeometry`. I feel like the vertices are good but somehow when I had the indices I can't manage to make it work.

Indices

```
[0,2,1,2,3,1,4,6,5,6,7,5,8,10,9,10,11,9,12,14,13,14,15,13,16,18,17,18,19,17,20,22,21,22,23,21]
```

Vertices

```
[
    0.5,0.5,0.5,
    0.5,0.5,-0.5,
    0.5,-0.5,0.5,
    0.5,-0.5,-0.5,
    -0.5,0.5,-0.5,
    -0.5,0.5,0.5,
    -0.5,-0.5,-0.5,
    -0.5,-0.5,0.5,
    -0.5,0.5,-0.5,
    0.5,0.5,-0.5,
    -0.5,0.5,0.5,
    0.5,0.5,0.5,
    -0.5,-0.5,0.5,
    0.5,-0.5,0.5,
    -0.5,-0.5,-0.5,
    0.5,-0.5,-0.5,
    -0.5,0.5,0.5,
    0.5,0.5,0.5,
    -0.5,-0.5,0.5,
    0.5,-0.5,0.5,
    0.5,0.5,-0.5,
    -0.5,0.5,-0.5,
    0.5,-0.5,-0.5,
    -0.5,-0.5,-0.5
]
```

And here is the code

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
let gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

const vsSource = `
    attribute vec4 position;
    uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
    varying vec4 vColor;
    void main(void) {
      gl_Position = position;
    }
  `;

const fsSource = `  
    precision mediump float;
    varying vec4 vColor;
    void main(void) {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0);
    }
  `;

// Shader setup

let vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vsSource);
gl.compileShader(vertexShader);

if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    var log = gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader);
    throw "Shader compilation failed\n\n" + log + "\n\n";
}

var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fsSource);
gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);

if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    var log = gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader);
    throw "Shader compilation failed\n\n" + log + "\n\n";
}

let program = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);

gl.linkProgram(program);
gl.validateProgram(program);

if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    var log = gl.getProgramInfoLog(program);
    throw "Program link failed\n\n" + log;
}

gl.useProgram(program);

let modelViewMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "modelViewMatrix");

let model = mat4.create();

gl.uniformMatrix4fv(modelViewMatrix, false, model);

var vertices = new Float32Array([
    0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5
]);

var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

let position = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "position");

gl.vertexAttribPointer(position, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(position);

var indices = new Uint16Array([
    0,
    2,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    1,
    4,
    6,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    5,
    8,
    10,
    9,
    10,
    11,
    9,
    12,
    14,
    13,
    14,
    15,
    13,
    16,
    18,
    17,
    18,
    19,
    17,
    20,
    22,
    21,
    22,
    23,
    21
]);

var indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please use [snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) here, not fiddles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the index buffer you have used the array data type `Uint16Array`:

> var indices = new Uint16Array([...]);

So you have to use enumerator constant `gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT` rather than `gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE` for the data type parameter:

<s>`gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);`</s>

```js
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

---

Since the greatest index is less than 256, you can use the array data type `Uint8Array` rather than `Uint16Array`, but keep the enumerator constant `gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE`:

```js
var indices = new Uint8Array([...]);
```

```js
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```